# ViewBag Append In Onclick Button MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to retrieve a string value from viewbag and append it with a javascript function.

```
<input type="button" value="Open" id="relay1Cuc1" onclick="newAJAXCommand(@ViewBag.Address1+'/io.cgi?DOA1=20');">
```

I load the ViewBag value from controller in this mode:

```
 ViewBag.Address1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cucina1Address"];
```

The result of which I need in onclick is as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="Open" id="relay1Cuc1" onclick="newAJAXCommand('192.168.0.1/io.cgi?DOA2=20');">
```

Thanks

Comment: So what result are you getting?

Comment: No result. It's not the correct way to write the viewbag. I want to know the correct mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Open" id="relay1Cuc1" onclick="newAJAXCommand('@(ViewBag.Address1)/io.cgi?DOA2=20');">
```

Comment: In my case it does not work ... it's as if it does not close the @ . the input is not clickable

Comment: in this case there is another problem then, not razor. can you see on firebug if there's an error on javascript?

Comment: I have solved the other problem and it works fine. Thank you